# Functional Puzzle Solving

Tags: lateral-thinking, enigmatic-puzzle

A professor has written a note to help him remember his password. I'm sure you can find out what it is. After all, he's very functional.

$\text{4,24 AOPCRTLIFA}$
$\text{10,5 RAVHLE}$
$\text{0,1 SIOEICN}$
$\text{3,27 BEUMC}$
$\text{54,18 ETEITNTO}$
$\text{100,2 LHOIGAMCTR}$
$\text{16,4 UOATRSROOEQ}$
$\text{0,-1/2 UATZE}$
$\text{6,18 IELPRNT}$
$\text{140,12 MSGTAI}$

$\text{My password:}$
$\text{41,2,72,21,12,42,2,71,25,6,2,39}$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> MATHEMATICAL

Here's how to find it.

> Each set of letters anagram a mathematical function that can be applied to the first number to produce the second. (I actually didn't realize the relationship between the number until I had found most of them by recognizing near-anagrams).
>  
>
>  `4,24   FACTORIAL + P
>
>  10,5   HALVE + R
>
>  1,0    COSINE + I
>
>  3,27   CUBE + M
>
>  54,18  TOTIENT + E
>
>  100,2  LOGARITHM + C
>
>  16,4   SQUARE ROOT + O
>
>  0,-1/2 ZETA + U
>
>  6,18   TRIPLE + N
>
>  140,12 SIGMA + T`

From here,

> The extra letters spell "PRIME COUNT". Applying the prime count function (number of primes $\leq n$) to each number gives $12, 0, 19, 7, 4, 12, 0, 19, 8, 2, 0, 11,$ which as alphabet letters spells MATHEMATICAL.

Comment: Great puzzle! The whole process felt smooth and justified. I like the recursive step to get the final answer. I have some really nitpicky nitpicks. Since the ordering of the letters to anagram is arbritary (unless I'm missing something), convention is to write them alphabetically. I'd find a 1-indexed alphabet a bit more natural than 0-indexed. Commas are a bit weird to represent functions, though maybe $a \to b$ would be a giveaway, but if so the final clue should avoid commas and be space-separated.

Comment: To my knowlege, the last 'sub-puzzle' is one indexed, not zero indexed (?). Take 2. The number of primes <= 2 is one, so 2 -> 1 -> 'A'. But you're right, in that the solution phrase should probably not be separated by commas, and you also picked that I tried not to use `->` to avoid giving the game away too early.

Comment: @Tryth My mistake, it was indeed one-indexed.

Comment: @xnor : 100,2  LOGARMITH + C should be LOGARITHM

Comment: LOGARITHM -> ALGORITHM